# How to find and print twin primes?

Tags: c++

I have a homework problem wherein I need to find and print twin primes from 0 to 1000. For some reason though, my loop that prints the prime numbers stops working at the 617/619 twin prime and suddenly begins working again for twin primes over 1019.

```
int main()
{
    int count, prime1, prime2, number;

    const int primetot = 1500;
    count = 0;
    number = 2;

    bool check1;
    check1 = false;

    prime1 = 0;
    prime2 = 0;



        while (count < primetot)
        {
            count++;
            
            if (isprime(number) == true)
            {
                if (check1 == false)
                {
                    prime1 = number;
                    check1 = true;
                }
                else if (check1 == true)
                {
                    prime2 = number;
                    check1 = false;
                }

                if (prime2 - prime1 == 2)
                {
                    cout << "(" << prime1 << ", " << prime2 << ")" << endl;
                }

            }

            number++ ;

        }

    return 0;
}
```

I've troubleshot just about everything else and I can't seem to find an error in any other part of the code. The loop continues to run after 619 it just doesn't print.

Comment: If you have a pattern like `primeA, large gap, primeB, primeB+2` you'll miss the `primeB` pair. You'll assign `prime1 = primeA`, then `prime2 = primeB` - those are not 2 apart. Then start again with `prime1 = primeB+2`.

Comment: Even before we get as far as 617, this code misses either 3/5 or 5/7; it can't possibly find both.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, what is the missing output? (What are the twin primes between 619 and 1019?)

Comment: In C++ you rarely need to do `if (x == true)`, you can almost always do just `if (x)`. The shorter form is a lot more concise and familiar to C++ programmers. The `== true` check implies there's something strange going on.

Comment: Ah, I found a list that goes high enough. (The question would still be more precise if it stated a specific pair of twin primes as an example of what was skipped.) Looks like the next pair is `641, 643`.  You might want to do some step-by-step debugging of your code starting when `number` is `641`. *(Many debuggers support conditional breakpoints. Or add something like `if ( number >= 641 ) std::cerr << number << '\n';` and set a breakpoint on the `std::cerr` line since that will not be hit by earlier iterations.)*